# Modifying Slider Function for Decimal Precision (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with the WordPress Traveler theme. In the Tour option, there is a slider used for Max People. Max People will be used for another purpose and should work with a precision of 0.1 instead of integers. To achieve this, I made changes in the files: wp-content\plugins\traveler-code\st-option-tree\includes\ot-functions-option-types.php and wp-content\plugins\st-option-tree\includes\ot-functions-option-types.php.

I modified the `ot_type_numeric_slider function`:

```
function ot_type_numeric_slider($args = array())
{
    extract($args); // phpcs:ignore

    // Check for description.
    $has_desc = !empty($field_desc);

    // Min, max, step options.
    $_options = explode(',', $field_min_max_step);
    $min = isset($_options[0]) ? floatval($_options[0]) : 0;
    $max = isset($_options[1]) ? floatval($_options[1]) : 100;
    $step = isset($_options[2]) ? floatval($_options[2]) : 0.1;

    // Format setting outer wrapper.
    echo '<div class="format-setting type-numeric-slider ' . ($has_desc ? 'has-desc' : 'no-desc') . '">';

    // Description.
    echo $has_desc ? '<div class="description">' . wp_kses_post(htmlspecialchars_decode($field_desc)) . '</div>' : '';

    // Format setting inner wrapper.
    echo '<div class="format-setting-inner">';

    echo '<div class="ot-numeric-slider-wrap">';

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr($field_name) . '" id="' . esc_attr($field_id) . '" class="ot-numeric-slider-hidden-input" value="' . esc_attr($field_value) . '" data-min="' . esc_attr($min) . '" data-max="' . esc_attr($max) . '" data-step="' . esc_attr($step) . '">';

    echo '<input type="text" class="ot-numeric-slider-helper-input widefat option-tree-ui-input ' . esc_attr($field_class) . '" value="' . esc_attr($field_value) . '" readonly>';

    echo '<div id="ot_numeric_slider_' . esc_attr($field_id) . '" class="ot-numeric-slider"></div>';

    echo '</div>';

    echo '</div>';

    echo '</div>';
}
```

So I changed below part:

```
$_options = explode(',', $field_min_max_step);
$min      = isset($_options[0]) ? $_options[0] : 0;
$max      = isset($_options[1]) ? $_options[1] : 100;
$step     = isset($_options[2]) ? $_options[2] : 1;
```

To:

```
$_options = explode(',', $field_min_max_step);
$min = isset($_options[0]) ? floatval($_options[0]) : 0;
$max = isset($_options[1]) ? floatval($_options[1]) : 100;
$step = isset($_options[2]) ? floatval($_options[2]) : 0.1;
```

After implementing these changes, the slider still operates with integers. I don't see anything else related to the slider in this file, and the support mentioned that the changes should be made only in this file. **What could have gone wrong?**

Comment: Maybe there is a value for the `$_options[2]` variable?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `isset($_options[2]) ? floatval($_options[2]) : 0.1` you are checking for the value of $_option[2], otherwise you are setting it as `0.1`, maybe that variable already has some value.

Comment: I don't see the step variable initialized anywhere. that is, it was in another file and I changed it to 0.1. Nothing helped

Comment: i may be a cache issue, make sure to purge all caches. and make sure you are editing the right file if it is a child theme. did you check console for errors ?

Comment: **Never change code in 3rd party plugins**. As soon as you update the plugin, all your changes will be wiped.

Comment: So what should I do in this case? 
This theme is so limited. Everything has to be changed in the code because nothing can be set.